# How do I display error messages with firebase 9

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The following code works, and I get an error back if there's an issue.
Note, this is vue code. Hence the `.value`

```js
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'

const register = async () => {
  loading.value = true
  let response
  try {
    const auth = getAuth()
    response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      form.value.email,
      form.value.password
    )
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  }
  loading.value = false

  return response
}
```

However, here's an example of what `error.message` returns:

```
Firebase: Password should be at least 6 characters (auth/weak-password).
```

My question. Is there a way to get a clean message back? By that, I mean without `Firebase:`  and `(auth/weak-password)`.

Or am I missing something here? Is there another way I'm supposed to deal with Firebases error object? Perhaps I'm supposed to take the `error.code` and write a custom message myself for every scenario?

Let me know if any other information is needed, and I'll update the question :)

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing, not sure why "message" includes the code within it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using helper function, but don't think it's the best solution. Is there any better one?

```js
function getRefinedFirebaseAuthErrorMessage(errorMesssage: string): string {
  return errorMesssage
    .replace('Firebase: ', '')
    .replace(/\(auth.*\)\.?/, '');
}
```

Notice that to force Firebase 9 to return an error message as `Firebase: {real, descriptive error message}. (auth/{code}).` it is necessary to init it with `errorMap` option set to `debugErrorMap`:

```js
import { FirebaseApp, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { Auth, initializeAuth, debugErrorMap } from 'firebase/auth';

const app: FirebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth: Auth = initializeAuth(app, { errorMap: debugErrorMap });
```

Otherwise, Firebase will return only error codes.

Comment: Any chance you found a more concise method in the end?

Answer (score -1):

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'

const register = async () => {
  loading.value = true
  let response
  try {
   if(form.value.password.length <= 6 ){
     return "Password should be at least 6 characters (auth/weak-password)"
   }

    const auth = getAuth()
    response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      form.value.email,
      form.value.password
    )
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  }
  loading.value = false

  return response
}
```

Comment: This is just frontend validation, not really a solution. It would mean I have to catch all possible errors myself on the frontend, and why do that if firebase supplies a response with errors anyway?